# Handling AJAX response with jQuery $.ajax in Django application

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, ajax, django

I'm making an ajax call to the server and want to receive an array for further processing. I'm a beginner and quite confused about what I'm really doing. Below is a snippet that I came up with so far. It works well until I try to process the returned data. I think my problem is that I don't really understand how to form a correct response and how to process it.

**JAVASCRIPT/JQUERY:**

```
var shoppingList = {
    // SOME CODE BEFORE

    'foodIngredients' : function() {
        // Send a list of food ids and receive an array of necessary ingredients. Make the returned array unique.
        $.ajax({
            url: 'http://localhost:8000/ingredients/',
            // ingredients.html template:
            // [{% for item in ingredients %}{% if forloop.last %}{{ item.id }}{% else %}{{ item.id }},{% endif %}{% endfor %}]
            type: 'POST',
            data: JSON.stringify(shoppingList.selectedFoods),
            dataType: 'text',
            cache: 'false',
            success: function(result){
                console.log(result); // [33,85,88,89,91]
                shoppingList.returnedIngredients = result;
                shoppingList.uniqueIngredients = _.unique(shoppingList.returnedIngredients);
                console.log(shoppingList.uniqueIngredients); // [,3,,,8,5,9,1,] <-- NOT OK; Expected [33,85,88,89,91]
            }
    });
    },

    // SOME CODE AFTER
};
```

**INGREDIENTS VIEW:**

```
def ingredients(request):
    if request.is_ajax():
        ourid = json.loads(request.raw_post_data)
        ingredients = Ingredience.objects.filter(food__id__in=ourid)
        t = get_template('ingredients.html')
        html = t.render(Context({'ingredients': ingredients,}))
        return HttpResponse(html)
    else:
        html = '<p>This is not ajax</p>'      
        return HttpResponse(html)
```

Comment: Can you paste the code of /ingredients/ view ?

Comment: @jpic: added ingredients view.

Comment: @jade: _.unique is a function from the underscore.js library: http://underscorejs.org/#uniq

Comment: `result` is a string, not an array of numbers. So `_.unique` is returning the unique characters in the string. You need to use `jSON.Parse` to translate the result to an array. Or specify `dataType: 'json'` in the options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

result is a string, not an array of numbers. So _.unique is returning the unique characters in the string. You need to use `jSON.Parse` to translate the result to an array. Or specify `dataType: 'json'` in the options.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Simply specifying ̣̣`dataType: 'json'` solved the issue. I still don't understand how come it works. Isn't json supposed to be in the `key : value` format?

Comment: JSON can be used to encode almost any kind of JavaScript data. Ifit's an object it's `{key:value, key:value}`, if it's an array it's `[element, element, element]`.